# What is the simplest way of creating semi-transparent images

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to create a game that uses buttons (and text areas) that are semi-transparent (Alpha of about 60%).  I can do almost everything I want in XHTML and CSS, except for these semi-transparent items.  So I'm looking for the easiest way of creating semi-transparent images on my web pages.

Ideas so far:

1. Create PNGs with semi-transparent pixels.  This is supposed to be possible, and there are well-defined interfaces for defining an Alpha channel using PHP and the GD package.  Problem: I tried this, but the images were opaque in all the browsers I tried (Chrome, IE8, FF).
2. Do it in Flash.  I know how to use Flash(*) from some work I did before I retired.  Problem: Flash is priced for the professional developer, not the hobbyist.

(*) Well, Flash 8.  But as I understand it, even with newer versions I can continue to create movie clips the old way, they just get translated into a bunch of AS.  And it's supposedly possible to continue using AS2, although you can't mix AS2 and AS3.

1. Do it in Flex.  Problem: interfaces best described as arcane.  Even using suggestions from experienced Flex developers, trying to include code from another mxml file (other than as a class) was a PITA.
2. Use SVG.  This looked promising.  The SVG syntax is basically XML, the element tags are reasonably obvious, and the interaction of attributes only slightly arcane, and there are plenty of examples in the tutorial.  But... about half of current browsers will not support using SVG in an <img> tag.  You have to use <embed>  That means you can't put it inside an <a> or <button>.  Even using embed, I got what look like "broken image" icons in IE8.

As I'm writing this, I notice several items under "similar questions" that look promising.  But when I look at them, they use attributes that are not mentioned in the CSS spec: opacity, filter:alpha, and rgba.  When working in a complex language, I really prefer to have the complete language spec open in another window, or to have the equivalent dead-trees version (e.g., the O'Reilly salmon book *Cascading Style Sheets, The Definitive Guide*, which sits on a bookshelf next to my desk.

So I'm asking for recommendations.  If the consensus is to use SVG, I'll post my code and see if people can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you don't mind a quite rustic style, you can do the "one pixel opaque and one pixel transparent" trick with a GIF image. It is like a chess board, where all the squares of one colour are set to transparent.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img shows that 85.45% of the browsers today do in fact support svg in img tags, what is your source for "about half of current browsers will not support using SVG in an <img> tag"?

Comment: Okay, maybe it's just IE and a couple of others.  But IE still retains a fair-sized market share, even though most "sensible" people use FF, Chrome, Safari, or Opera.  ("sensible people" of course, are people like you and me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS "opacity" property is perfectly valid.  It is part of CSS3, and is supported in all browsers (*).

http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

Or you can use semi-transparent PNGs, as Alvaro demonstrated.  They should work just fine.  Not sure what happened with your attempts, but you must have done something wrong.

- Note for versions of IE <= 8, you need to use the "filter" property instead.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: Yes, I must have done something wrong.  I have uploaded my code to http://www.nyx.net/~bgold/mainmenu.php    and
http://www.nyx.net/~bgold/displayable/MainMenuButton.php

Comment: Can you describe the image you were attempting to create in that second file?  I haven't used these PHP methods myself. But from the documentation, it appears you are creating an image with a completely transparent grey background (ie not visible) with some opaque white text on it.  Was that what you wanted?

Comment: No, it's a rectangle with 55% opacity and white text on it.

Sorry, I left in some code that I'd put in to test various levels of opacity to see what effect they had on the image (none).  The correct value is: $alpha = round(128 * 0.45)  [I hope]

Comment: I'm getting the effects I want with CSS, but I still want to know how to do it with PHP.  I maybe be retired, but I still want to learn.

Comment: It looks like you may have to call imagesavealpha($button, true) after calling imagecreatetruecolor().  See http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what problem you have with PNG's. Imo the best and easiest option by far. And they look as they should in all browsers from my own experience.

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/BDLYG/

```
(and here a code I need to add)
```

Comment: That looks promising.  There's an example of an image with alpha channel in the PHP manual (section on GD package), so that should work okay.  I also want to do gradients (have the image fade into the background as it extends to the right).  Those are easy to do in SVG, but I'll have to write a program.  Luckily, there's an example.  The one problem I see is that it may take longer than I like to build the image pixel by pixel (actually, line by line in the example).  But if I can store the already-built image on my server I can just overlay the text on it using CSS.  So that's tempting.

Comment: Well. As I have been working with photoshop for many years, make any type of trasparent gradiant on an image, any direction, any intensity (for example 100% opacity left side to 50% right side) takes nothing but a few minutes... If You need help badly and not many images are needed to transform in your proyect I could do it for You. (but monday has to be).

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro.  I have only a few images.

Comment: Thanks, @AlvaroMendez.  I have only a few images.

1. A bar 35px high, 450px wide, rgb(38,45,22) opacity: 55%

2. A bar 35px by 400px, rgb(96,96,96), opacity 75%.  It then fades to full transparency over the next 200px horizontal.

3. A horizontal orange bar.  I'm going to try paste the code for that in a separate comment.

Comment: Nope, the code is too long for a comment.  I've uploaded it: 
http://www.nyx.net/~bgold/orangebar.svg  (to see what it looks like)
http://www.nyx.net/~bgold/orangebar.svg.txt (for the code)

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have most users with the 'modern' browsers, I would say go with SVG. If you do, post here, and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Does IE8 count as "modern"?  I think I was able to view an SVG image by itself, but when I embedded one in a larger page, I got the "broken image" icon.

Comment: Another problem with SVG: I can't put the <embed> element inside an <a> or <button> element, so if I want to go to another page when the SVG-built button is clicked, I have to put the link _inside_ the SVG <a xlink:href="...">

But then if I click on the iamge, the new page comes up _inside_ the embed, rather than replacing the whole page.  Not what I want, at all.

Comment: Try placing the svg file inside of an <img> e.g. <a href="..."><img  src="myDbg.svg" width="58" height="58" /></a>, or include the <img> inside a button

Comment: That works in Chrome.  Fails miserably in IE and some other browsers. See the tutorial (you can get there from the External Links section of the Wiki article).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the useful answers.  I'm currently using a combination of CSS and PNGs (generated via PHP).  I could have gotten along with just CSS, but I decided I wanted to change the opacity of the background when the user hovers over the button -- but keep the text opaque.  It's easy to change the opacity of the whole thing, but (as far as I can tell) not of just the background.

I also experimented with SVG, and it also works fine, but it requires extra computation so I chose the simpler (for me) approach of CSS and PHP.  I'm already comfortable with those two languages, just needed to be introduced to the newer stuff in CSS3 and the one extra function call needed to make alpha work in PNGs generated by the PHP GD package.